# fetch for defects not fetching across user, iteration, and project

Tags: javascript, rally

I have researched and tried everything that I can think of to try and retrieve the actual values for the Iteration, Project, and User columns but I can never get the column data to populate for those like the name of the iteration, name of the project, and name of the submitted by user. I have read that it should be fine to do in the fetch the way I have it and others have said that you have to specify the types with something like this

```
types : ['defect','user','iteration','project'],
```

When I do that I dont ever load my grid. I have tried things like this as recommended by some

```
defect.Iteration.Name
```

OR

```
Iteration.Name
```

I could really use some help here. I also read one article saying the WSAPI no longer supports this kind of request and has to be handled in multiple queries/fetches. Anywho, here is the code that I am using...

```
function onLoad() {
var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(
                '__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                '__PROJECT_OID__',
                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
var config = {
              type : 'defect',
              key  : 'defects',       
              columnKeys : ["FormattedID", "Name", "Priority125", "Iteration", "Project", "SubmittedBy", "CreationDate", "ScheduleState", "State"],
              fetch : 'FormattedID,Name,Priority125,Iteration,Project,SubmittedBy,CreationDate,ScheduleState,State',
              query : '((State != "Closed") OR (ScheduleState != "Accepted"))',
              order : 'Priority125'
              };
var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config, rallyDataSource);
table.display("tableDiv");
}
rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things needed in order to get this to work as you're wanting:

1. You can fetch recursively up to a level of one deep. Thus if you want to grab a Defect's Name, Formatted ID, and the Project Name, your fetch would look like:
2. fetch: "Name,FormattedID,Project,Name"
3. Grab the data via rallyDataSource.findAll()
4. Post-process the data so that you feed your table all string data. I.e. clobber Object Reference fields like Project, with the Project Name instead.
5. Finally, populate and display the table.

Here's working example that illustrates what I think you're wanting to do (minus the "Priority 125" custom field that you have defined).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2011  Rally Software Development Corp.  All rights reserved -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Defect Information</title>
    <meta name="Name"    content="Defect Information" />
    <meta name="Version" content="1.32" />
    <meta name="Vendor"  content="Rally Software" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.32/sdk.js?debug=True"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var rallyDataSource = null;
        var table = null;

        function showTable(results) {

            if (table) {
                table.destroy();
            }

            var tableConfig = {
                columnKeys   : ["FormattedID", "Name", "Iteration", "Project", "SubmittedBy", "CreationDate", "ScheduleState", "State"],
                columnWidths : ["85px",        "350px", "90px",      "100px",  "100px",       "120px",         "100px",         "100px" ]
            };

           table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tableConfig);

            // Loop through the rows and clobber object attributes of the results collection with
            // string values
            for(var i = 0; i < results.defects.length; i++){

                thisDefect = results.defects[i];

                var iterationName = "";
                // Grab value fields
                if (thisDefect.Iteration != null) {
                    iterationName = results.defects[i].Iteration.Name;
                } else {
                    iterationName = "Un-scheduled";
                }
                var projectName = thisDefect.Project.Name;

                // Re-map SubmittedBy object to SubmittedBy string
                submittedByDisplayName = thisDefect.SubmittedBy === null ? "": thisDefect.SubmittedBy._refObjectName;                

                // Clober objects with values
                results.defects[i].Iteration = iterationName;
                results.defects[i].Project = projectName;
                results.defects[i].SubmittedBy = submittedByDisplayName;
            }

            table.addRows(results.defects);
            table.display(document.getElementById('defectsDiv'));
        }


        function onLoad() {
            rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(
                    '__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                    '__PROJECT_OID__',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

            var config = {
              type : 'defect',
              key  : 'defects',       
              fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,SubmittedBy,Iteration,Name,Project,Name,CreationDate,ScheduleState,State',
              query : '((State != "Closed") OR (ScheduleState != "Accepted"))',
            };
            rallyDataSource.findAll(config, showTable);
            rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.38");
        }

        rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="aDiv"></div>
<div style="font-weight: bold;"><p>Defects</p></div>
<div id="defectsDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Lesson learned on this api, thanks for all of your help!